# Spark/Hadoop job not running in parralel

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, parallel-processing, mapreduce

I think I am having a beginner bug but I really don't know how to fix it and it's driving me nuts.
I have a cluster made of 2 machines:

1. 8GB RAM (6.9 usable), 4 Cores, Win10 : runs a master, a worker, and it's also the machine from which I am running the java driver program (from IntelliJ)
2. 2GB RAM (1.3 usable), 4 Cores, Ubuntu 16.04 on VM(runned in VBox) : runs a worker

I have a class Network and I want to generate Networks in a for loop by starting from a list with a single network and then by transforming each network into N new networks using flatmap. After that I have a filter and a count. Steps:

```
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    List<Network> data = Arrays.asList(new Network());
    JavaRDD<Network> currentN = sc.parallelize(data);
    for(int k=1;k<=10;k++) {
        JavaRDD<Network> newN = currentN.flatMap(new MyFlatMap());
        currentN = newN;
    }
    JavaRDD<Network> filteredNetworks = currentN.filter(new MyFilter());
    System.out.println(filteredNetworks.count());
```

The algorithm works and outputs the correct value.

However, by comparing the duration of the application in different scenarios, I tend to think that the application is not runned in parallel:

Cluster that uses both machines, with a total of 2GB of Ram and 8 Cores: **Duration 1,5 min**

Cluster that uses only the second machine(VM Ubuntu), 1GB RAM, 4 Cores : **Duration 1,1 min**

Cluster that uses only the first machine(which is a master, a worker, and the driver), 1GB RAM, 4 Cores: **Duration 3,2 min**

Screenshots of my spark UI:

**Alive Workers**
[image: Alive workers]

**Event timeline of first run (with both machines):**
[image: Event timeline of first run]

**Aggregates metrics by executor (with both machines)**
[image: Metrics]

I don't know why the machine that runs Ubuntu in a Virtual Machine is faster than the main machine (which is master,worker and driver program) because the main machine has a better CPU(i7 2.6GHZ compared to i3 1,9GHZ).

But the main problem is **why running on a single machine is faster than running on both?** Shouldn't it be the other way around? My guess is that the RDD is not computed in parallel. If this is the case, could you please explain why and how I could make it to be processed in parallel?

**Explanation of what the job does:**

Basically,this is what I want to achieve in the for loop:

I start with an RDD of 1 Network (it's not a file, it's just a small class).

In the for loop I use flatMap to transform 1 Network into 10 new Networks.

Iteration0: currentN = 1 Network -> flatMap -> currentN = 10 Networks

Iteration1: currentN = 10 Networks -> flatMap -> currentN = 100 Networks

.
.

Iteration9: currentN = 10^8 Networks -> flatMap -> currentN = 10^9 Networks

So as I said, I am **generating the input**. And I want to do this generate in parallel, so this means that the flatMap needs to be done in parallel. To achieve this, spark should:

1. Take the RDD with N networks
2. Divide the RDD into 8 partitions for each core, each partition having N/8 Networks
3. Apply the flatMap on each machine in parallel, transforming each N/8 Networks into N/8*10 new Networks.
4. Repeat the steps on each machine, doing the generation with flatMap in parallel.
5. After the for loop has ended, each machine should have 10^9 / 8 Networks. Filter them in parallel and then count the number of elements in each RDD on each machine, in parralel and output the answer.

This is what I want to achieve but for some reason the flatMap generation in the for loop is done only on one machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this. The bug was so silly and obvious but took me so long to figure it out...

As I mentioned earlier, I am not reading the input from a file, but instead I generate the input starting from **1 Network** and then I do flatMap on that network to get N networks, than I get N*M new networks and so on.

But because I start from only 1 Network, when I do

```
List<Network> data = Arrays.asList(new Network());
JavaRDD<Network> currentN = sc.parallelize(data);
```

The data gets parallelized only on one CPU, in one task, because the RDD contains only 1 element, hence the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The last screenshot from the spark UI, shows that on your 8 tasks, 7 were completed with a maximum time of 37 ms, while the longest task was running for at least 46 seconds.

If you have one task that run for 3 minutes while the others run for less than a second, your distributed computation is not balanced and therefore you cannot take advantage of having multiple machines running altogether because the computationnal time is constrained by your longest task.

That behaviour is often caused by inputs of unbalanced sizes (7 files of 1 Ko and 1 file of 1 Go) of by an unbalanced operation/transformation (`join`, ...).

Finally its very hard to explain your timing vs CPU without knowing exactly what is your job, but a potential explanation is that you have a data intensive job (and not CPU intensive jobs) and therefore the bottleneck is the hard drive (SSD on the machine with slowest CPU).

Comment: I used  **conf.set("spark.default.parallelism","8")** to make the cluster use all the 8 cores so that's why the UI shows 8 tasks, but only one really does the counting stage, and this is basically the only job. As you can see, I don't use files as input, but I'm rather generating the input in each iteration of the for loop using flatMap. So I really don't know why the generate phase in the for loop is not runned in parallel.

Comment: I edited the original question and added explanation of what I want to achieve. Maybe this helps you understand what happens because I really need help with this one.

Comment: What happen if you use the `repartition` opérator inside the loop.